# HSTS via customResponseHeaders on BackendConfig in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to enable HSTS for multiple applications behind a load balancer in GKE. I see documentation for adding custom **request** headers, but not custom **response** headers. When I switch out `customRequestHeaders` for `customResponseHeaders` in the BackendConfig resource definition, the following error occurs:

```
Error: Failed to morph manifest to OAPI type

  with module.ephemeral_kolibri_v015_env.module.k8s.kubernetes_manifest.bck_iap_backendconfig,
  on ../environments/modules/resources/k8s/services.tf line 13, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "bck_iap_backendconfig":
  13: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "bck_iap_backendconfig" {

AttributeName("spec"): [AttributeName("spec")] failed to morph object element into object element: AttributeName("spec").AttributeName("customResponseHeaders"): [AttributeName("spec").AttributeName("customResponseHeaders")] failed to morph object element into object element:
AttributeName("spec").AttributeName("customResponseHeaders"): type is nil
```

How can I configure the GKE ingress to add custom response headers?

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://serverfault.com/a/1050590/683878) which is similar to your problem but this is of  Google Container Engine. You can also follow the [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1106) for more information on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the BackendConfig resource does not currently support `customResponseHeaders` so you won't be able to get this working using GKE Ingress.  But you should be able to make this work by using [standalone NEGs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#how_to) and then [attaching them to an existing GCE load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#attaching_a_load_balancer_to_your_standalone_negs) on which you can configure custom response headers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gari Singh. There is a similar case in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/862862/how-can-i-enable-hsts-on-the-default-google-load-balancer-coming-with-google-con/1050590#1050590) but it is of Google container engine. On the understanding of the HSTS header, it lets a web site inform the browser that it should never load the site using HTTP and should automatically convert all attempts to access the site using HTTP to HTTPS requests instead. It consists of one HTTP header, Strict-Transport-Security, sent by the server with the resource.

The [custom response header availability](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers#working-with-response)  for Cloud Load Balancing, has no support for GKE ingress controller. You can try to configure your backend-service adding a custom response header using the Cloud Shell command line.

You can also follow the [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1106) for more information on this issue.